# best practices for passing initialization arguments to superclasses?

Tags: python-3.x, initialization, argparse, super

I'm trying to figure out the best way to initialize sub/superclasses in Python3. Both the base and subclasses will take half a dozen parameters, all of which will be parsed from command line arguments.

The obvious way to implement this is to parse all the args at once, and pass them all in:

```
class Base:
  def __init__(self, base_arg1, base_arg2, base_arg3):

class Sub(Base):
  def __init__(self, sub_arg1, sub_arg2, sub_arg3,
                     base_arg1, base_arg2, base_arg3):
    super().__init__(self, base_arg1, base_arg2, base_arg3)

main():
    # parse args here
    options = parser.parse_args()

    obj = Sub(options.sub_arg1, options.sub_arg2, options.sub_arg3,
              options.base_arg1, options.base_arg2, options.base_arg3)
```

If I have a Sub-subclass (which I will), things get really hairy in terms of the list of arguments passed up through successive super().**init**() calls.

But it occurs to me that argparse.parse_known_args() offers another path: I could have each subclass parse out the arguments it needs/recognizes and pass the rest of the arguments up the hierarchy:

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self, args):
        base_options = base_parser.parse_known_args(args)

class Sub(Base):
    def __init__(self, args):
        (sub_options, other_args) = sub_parser.parse_known_args(args)
        super().__init__(self, other_args)

main():
    obj = Sub(sys.argv)
```

This seems cleaner from an API point of view. But I can imagine that it violates some tenet of The Way Things Are Done In Python and is a bad idea for all sorts of reasons. My search of the web has not turned up any examples either way - could the mighty and all-knowing mind of Stack Overflow help me understand the Right Way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Look inside the `argparse.py` code.  An `ArgumentParser` is a subclass of an `_ActionsContainer`.  All the `actions` are subclasses of `Action`.

When you call

```
parser.add_argument('foo', action='store_action', ...)
```

the parameters are passed, mostly as `*args` and `**kwargs` to `_StoreAction`, which in turn passes them on to its `supper` (after a setting some defaults, etc).

As a module that is mean to be imported, and never run as a stand along script it does not have a `if __name__....` block.  But often I'll include such a block to invoke test code.  That's the place to put the commandline parser, or at least to invoke it.  If might be defined in a function in the body, but it normally shouldn't be called when module is imported.

In general `argparse` is a scripting tool, and shouldn't be part of a class definitions - unless you are a subclassing `ArgumentParser` to add some new functionality.

You might also want to look at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plac.  This package provides a different interface to `argparse`, and is a good example of subclassing this parser.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks hpaulj! I think your response helped me figure out an even simpler way to go about it. I can parse all the options at the top level, then just pass the option namespace in, and let each subclass pull out the ones it needs. Kind of face-palm simple, compared to the other approaches:

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self, options):
        base_arg1 = options.base_arg1
        base_arg2 = options.base_arg2

class Sub(Base):
    def __init__(self, options):
        super().__init__(self, options) # initialize base class
        sub_arg1 = options.sub_arg1
        sub_arg2 = options.sub_arg2

main():
    options = parser.parse_args()
    obj = Sub(options)
```